# cross OS file system that works on Windows 10+, Linux, and OS X

Tags: linux, windows, mac-osx, filesystems, cross-platform

First, I realize there are many duplicate questions but they are all quite old and their answers may not be relevant anymore. I would assume (or hope) that in our constantly evolving technology landscape there is now a better solution than using 3rd party, potentially buggy, drivers to read NTFS.

Is there?

- FAT32 has a size limit
- HFS+ is wonky in Linux, especially since CoreStorage (FileVault) is usually enabled by default
- exFAT works but based on online articles/comments it seems to have a lot of bugs/issues
- NTFS - requires 3rd party drivers/libraries that may not always be 100% perfect
- something better?!?!?!

Comment: Eh? Working NTFS drivers are in the Linux kernel. The problem is security and permissions. Every OS handles these differently, so there will never be such a filesystem. You need to figure out what you are going to use the filesystem for, and then you can choose an appropriate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have proposed exFAT, but you are right - it is buggy.
The next bet is NTFS - it works well with FUSE and easily automated with autofs.

You definitely should stay away from HFS+ - it's an abomination.